# How to add a package to the Debian ISO so that it's automatically installed

Tags: debian, debian-installer

I am following the manual here: [DebianInstaller/Modify/CD](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianInstaller/Modify/CD)

First I made a deb file(called mytest.deb). Then `bsdtar`ed a Debian ISO (`debian-10.1.0-amd64-netinst.iso`) into a directory called buster-iso, and made all its files writable and put that mytest.deb file in this path: `pool/main/m/`.

Then I made this config file for `apt-ftparchive`:

```
# config-deb

Dir {
    ArchiveDir "buster-iso";
};

# Sets the top of the .deb directory tree.
TreeDefault {
   Directory "pool/";
};

# The location for a Packages file.                
BinDirectory "pool/main" {
   Packages "dists/buster/main/binary-amd64/Packages";
};

# We are only interested in .deb files (.udeb for udeb files).                                
Default {
   Packages {
       Extensions ".deb";
    };
};
```

and ran `apt-ftparchive generate config-deb` and then ran the next three commands as in the manual as well(only with slight changes so that names will match with filenames I've used). I also confirmed that mytest.deb existed both in the `dists/buster/main/binary-amd64/Packages` and in the `md5sum.txt`.

Then I turned the whole directory back into a new ISO file(also according to the manual). Also the size of the newly generated ISO is correctly increased compared to the original one. But when I install this Debian, my deb package is not installed as expected.

I've tested the installation of my deb file already (with `dpkg -i mytest.deb`) on my own system and it's working fine. The hierarchy in this deb file is as simple as `usr/local` and a `mytest.tar.gz` file is in this path. I expect the file `/usr/local/mytest.tar.gz` to pre-exist when I install the new Debian ISO. But it's not there.

Maybe I've used a bad path and it's being overwritten by other procedures in the installation? Maybe I've misunderstood something in the manual? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You’ve successfully added your package to the ISO; that’s all that the linked instructions achieve. As you can see [further down in the instructions](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianInstaller/Modify/CD#Accessing_the_New_Image.27s_Archive), the result is that the custom package can be installed manually; but nothing in the installation image will cause it to be installed automatically.

If you want the package to be installed automatically, you’d have to make further changes. It might be possible to add parameters to the installer (I’d have to check); other possibilities include adding your package to the task selection (`tasksel`) or perhaps making it “Essential”.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, i hope anyone can find it helpful in the future.
The file is added packages hub/pool but not called for installation.

This can be achieved in number of ways

1. [Using debconf preseeding](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianInstaller/Preseed%20) 
   Con: few additional steps to unpack repack initrd.gz everytime you want to change preseed
2. [simple cdd](https://wiki.debian.org/Simple-CDD/Howto)
   Con: need to setup in a live system for the first time, and can be changed in unpacked iso from there